# Hashing a known set of strings to map uniquely into an array index

Tags: optimization, hash

I am playing around with the Chemical Elements and I would like to have a "simple" function that maps the elemental symbols into a unique index of an array. I know that there are Hashes implemented in many programming languages, but I am more interested in how you would generally approach a problem like this. On top of the elements I also included Me, Et, Ph and D - and thus the complete list of symbols looks like this:

Ag, Al, Ar, As, Au, B, Ba, Be, Bi, Br, C, Ca, Cd, Ce, Cl, Co, Cr, Cs, Cu, D, Dy, Er, Et, Eu, F, Fe, Ga, Gd, Ge, H, He, Hf, Hg, Ho, I, In, Ir, K, Kr, La, Li, Lu, Me, Mg, Mn, Mo, N, Na, Nb, Nd, Ne, Ni, O, Os, P, Pa, Pb, Pd, Ph, Pr, Pt, Rb, Re, Rh, Ru, S, Sb, Sc, Se, Si, Sm, Sn, Sr, Ta, Tb, Te, Th, Ti, Tl, Tm, U, V, W, Xe, Y, Yb, Zn, Zr

The "best" solution would be to have as low highest index as possible, and the computation of the index needs to be simple. How would you do? By some random trying I got a version with the higest index of 355 which is an efficiency of ~25% (88 symbols in 356 buckets) by using this formula:

```
A = CharcodeFirstLetter * 21 mod 325
B = CharcodeSecondLetter-60         'B is set to 0 if symbol does not have a second letter
index = A + B - 13
```

Is there any systematic way to create such formulas from a generic set of starting symbols?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just programmatically try a bunch of parameter values and take the best result. I made a string of your symbols and put a space for the second character where there was just one character. I found numerous examples that beat your 356 buckets. The best I've found so far is 238 buckets.

```
uint32_t A = (symbol[0]*207) % 232;
uint32_t B = (symbol[1] == ' ' ? 46 : symbol[1] - 60);
index = A+B-51;
```

Comment: I cheated and found a perfect hasher with only 90 buckets, so 22 redundants, see my answer :)

Comment: @sehe That's interesting, nice one! Did this just happen to work out or is this a standard way of doing it? How big does the look-up table get in general?

Comment: I think the GNU gperf documentation has details on that. Yes, it's a very old standard tool.

Comment: I'll take a good look at that at some point.

Comment: I've just completed my demo to have compile-time self-validation :) Cheers +1 for your efforts

Comment: Nice! You can actually reduce the function with one operation by: Replacing 46 with -5 [you need a signed integer then] and 60 with 111. Then index will be A+B. This can also be accomplished by padding the input with a "j" and setting B=symbol[1]-111

Answer (score 1):

You can devise a perfect hash. E.g. [with `gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html) I generated a hash that maps the 88 keys onto unique integers in the range [8..96].

The C++ code modernized into a constexpr function:

```cpp
constexpr inline uint8_t hash(std::string_view str) {
    constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 128> asso_values{
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 27,
        10, 8,  7,  56, 87, 55, 44, 57, 97, 84, 48, 46, 6,  12, 22, 97, 28, 20, 17, 89, 11, 9,
        79, 66, 53, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 7,  16, 64, 19, 6,  27, 26, 29, 25, 97, 97, 32, 61,
        34, 31, 97, 97, 10, 52, 36, 20, 97, 97, 97, 62, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97};

    unsigned hval = str.length();
    switch (hval) {
        default : hval += asso_values[static_cast<uint8_t>(str[1])]; [[fallthrough]];
        case 1  : hval += asso_values[static_cast<uint8_t>(str[0])]; break;
    }
    return hval;
}
```

Now you can perform the mappings at compile time even! The reverse mapping:

```cpp
constexpr inline std::string_view reverse_hash(uint8_t key) {
    constexpr std::string_view table = "              N D C W B V O NeNaCe"
                                       "CaBeBaCrS BrP NbTeTaNdSeCdCuPaSrNi"
                                       "PrTbReBiSbArPbCoClPdTiH RbSiThAuRu"
                                       "TlHePhMeAgSnLaI RhPtAlCsGeGaZrOsY "
                                       "ErIrLuDyHgHfMgLiGdHoEuMoTmAsMnSmYb"
                                       "K ScXeF ZnU     InEtFeKr";
    auto el = table.substr(key * 2, 2);
    while (el.ends_with(" "))
        el.remove_suffix(1);
    return el;
}
```

Check the mappings at compile-time!

```
static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ge")) == "Ge");
static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("H")) == "H");
```

Or indeed with some validation helpers:

```
constexpr inline bool valid_symbol(std::string_view s) {
    if (auto len = s.length(); len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && len >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH)
        return reverse_hash(hash(s)) == s;

    return false;
}

constexpr inline bool valid_key(uint8_t key) { return !reverse_hash(key).empty(); }
```

Validate at compiletime:

```
static_assert(valid_key(hash("Sc")));
static_assert(valid_key(7));
static_assert(valid_key(96));
static_assert(not valid_key(0));
static_assert(not valid_key(97));

static_assert(valid_symbol("Sc"));
static_assert(valid_symbol("Sn"));
static_assert(not valid_symbol("Sd"));
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6xhnfcxso)**

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string_view>
/* C++ code produced by gperf version 3.1 */
/* Command-line: gperf -L C++ -7 -C -G -E -m 100 test.txt  */
/* Computed positions: -k'1-2' */
/* Modernized by hand, @sehe */

enum {
    TOTAL_KEYWORDS  = 88,
    MIN_WORD_LENGTH = 1,
    MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 2,
    MIN_HASH_VALUE  = 7,
    MAX_HASH_VALUE  = 96
}; /* maximum key range = 90, duplicates = 0 */

constexpr inline uint8_t hash(std::string_view str) {
    constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 128> asso_values{
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97,
        97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 27,
        10, 8,  7,  56, 87, 55, 44, 57, 97, 84, 48, 46, 6,  12, 22, 97, 28, 20, 17, 89, 11, 9,
        79, 66, 53, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 7,  16, 64, 19, 6,  27, 26, 29, 25, 97, 97, 32, 61,
        34, 31, 97, 97, 10, 52, 36, 20, 97, 97, 97, 62, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97};

    unsigned hval = str.length();
    switch (hval) {
        default : hval += asso_values[static_cast<uint8_t>(str[1])]; [[fallthrough]];
        case 1  : hval += asso_values[static_cast<uint8_t>(str[0])]; break;
    }
    return hval;
}

constexpr inline std::string_view reverse_hash(uint8_t key) {
    constexpr std::string_view table = "              N D C W B V O NeNaCe"
                                       "CaBeBaCrS BrP NbTeTaNdSeCdCuPaSrNi"
                                       "PrTbReBiSbArPbCoClPdTiH RbSiThAuRu"
                                       "TlHePhMeAgSnLaI RhPtAlCsGeGaZrOsY "
                                       "ErIrLuDyHgHfMgLiGdHoEuMoTmAsMnSmYb"
                                       "K ScXeF ZnU     InEtFeKr";
    auto el = table.substr(key * 2, 2);
    while (el.ends_with(" "))
        el.remove_suffix(1);
    return el;
}

constexpr inline bool valid_symbol(std::string_view s) {
    if (auto len = s.length(); len <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH && len >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH)
        return reverse_hash(hash(s)) == s;

    return false;
}

constexpr inline bool valid_key(uint8_t key) { return !reverse_hash(key).empty(); }

int main() {
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ag")) == "Ag");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Al")) == "Al");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ar")) == "Ar");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("As")) == "As");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Au")) == "Au");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("B")) == "B");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ba")) == "Ba");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Be")) == "Be");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Bi")) == "Bi");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Br")) == "Br");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("C")) == "C");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ca")) == "Ca");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Cd")) == "Cd");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ce")) == "Ce");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Cl")) == "Cl");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Co")) == "Co");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Cr")) == "Cr");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Cs")) == "Cs");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Cu")) == "Cu");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("D")) == "D");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Dy")) == "Dy");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Er")) == "Er");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Et")) == "Et");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Eu")) == "Eu");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("F")) == "F");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Fe")) == "Fe");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ga")) == "Ga");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Gd")) == "Gd");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ge")) == "Ge");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("H")) == "H");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("He")) == "He");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Hf")) == "Hf");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Hg")) == "Hg");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ho")) == "Ho");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("I")) == "I");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("In")) == "In");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ir")) == "Ir");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("K")) == "K");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Kr")) == "Kr");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("La")) == "La");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Li")) == "Li");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Lu")) == "Lu");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Me")) == "Me");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Mg")) == "Mg");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Mn")) == "Mn");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Mo")) == "Mo");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("N")) == "N");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Na")) == "Na");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Nb")) == "Nb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Nd")) == "Nd");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ne")) == "Ne");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ni")) == "Ni");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("O")) == "O");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Os")) == "Os");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("P")) == "P");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Pa")) == "Pa");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Pb")) == "Pb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Pd")) == "Pd");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ph")) == "Ph");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Pr")) == "Pr");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Pt")) == "Pt");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Rb")) == "Rb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Re")) == "Re");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Rh")) == "Rh");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ru")) == "Ru");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("S")) == "S");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Sb")) == "Sb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Sc")) == "Sc");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Se")) == "Se");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Si")) == "Si");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Sm")) == "Sm");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Sn")) == "Sn");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Sr")) == "Sr");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ta")) == "Ta");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Tb")) == "Tb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Te")) == "Te");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Th")) == "Th");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Ti")) == "Ti");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Tl")) == "Tl");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Tm")) == "Tm");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("U")) == "U");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("V")) == "V");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("W")) == "W");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Xe")) == "Xe");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Y")) == "Y");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Yb")) == "Yb");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Zn")) == "Zn");
    static_assert(reverse_hash(hash("Zr")) == "Zr");

    static_assert(valid_key(hash("Sc")));
    static_assert(valid_key(7));
    static_assert(valid_key(96));
    static_assert(not valid_key(0));
    static_assert(not valid_key(97));

    static_assert(valid_symbol("Sc"));
    static_assert(valid_symbol("Sn"));
    static_assert(not valid_symbol("Sd"));
}
```

All the code compiles down to

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Comment: Expanded the demo with static-asserts of all symbols and their reverse mappings, as well as tests for the validation functions.

Comment: I only noticed now that I was finding this question outside my standard tags ([tag:boost] and [tag:c++]). You could of course port the generated tables to your language of choice.

Comment: It feels little like cheating to use a fixed array of 128 integers to do the mapping. No sure if I would judge this as "simple calculation". But, I appreciate if this is the standard way, and that more or less all overhead comes at compile time. However, one of my key interest was the 'mathematical optimization approach' - if there was any structured way to get my 'simple' function f(char1, char2) => N mapping to a small subset of N.

Comment: You're looking at the result of the mathematical way. Also it does look a lot like you can replace the array with a switch, but it will probably take as much space in instructions. To learn more about the method gperf implements to generate this hash you can click through to the project documentation. I seen to remember having read about it in the past.